# display partially black, xrandr hangs 10 seconds before output

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I have a very odd problem with my three-display (one of which is scaled, and one rotated) Ubuntu 18.04 system. There are several symptoms I've noticed so far.

What matters most is that I have a 1080 HD display in my configuration that is rotated 90 degrees. It should, therefore, have a maximum Y coordinate of 1919 (since we start at zero). However, this is not the case. I see several symptoms:

- the bottom "inch or so" of that display is black
- if I move the cursor to that point, its Y coordinate is 1799
- the cursor will not move into the black region
- if I maximize an application window, part of it disappears into the black region--xwininfo shows that the window has a full 1920 height, even though the last 120 pixels are not being displayed.
- there is another screen in my system which is running scaled (so it actually displays 1280x720, but with a hardware scanning resolution of 1920x1080). The lowest point on this display has an absolute Y coordinate of 1799.
- if I take a screen shot of my displays, I get an image with 1800 pixels height, but the width (which should be 3000 pixels) is 5750 pixels.

As a secondary observation, if I exectute "xrandr" at the command line, it freezes the display entirely (the text cursor doesn't even visually make it to the newline!) for about 10 seconds, then everything returns to normal.

A side observation is that until yesterday, I had a different display with a 1280x1024 resolution in the rotated position instead of this 1920x1080 one. With that in place, there were no problems at all.

Here's the xrandr script I use to configure this on login:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --primary
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.6666x0.6666 --pos 420x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate left
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome, and of course, I'll be happy to provide more info/logs/whatever that might help.

EDIT:

1. I modified my xrandr configuration so that the screens that work properly are now 200 pixels "lower" on the y coordinate. At this point, the whole thing works well, so all urgency is gone. It would be nice to understand this however, and I suspect it might represent a bug in something.
2. Here's my graphics card info:

   $ hwinfo --gfxcard
   20: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
   [Created at pci.378]
   Unique ID: _Znp.oFJOiaTeLh5
   SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
   SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
   Hardware Class: graphics card
   Device Name: "Onboard IGD"
   Model: "Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
   Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
   Device: pci 0x0412 "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
   SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
   SubDevice: pci 0x05a4
   Revision: 0x06
   Driver: "i915"
   Driver Modules: "i915"
   Memory Range: 0xf7800000-0xf7bfffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
   Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xefffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
   I/O Ports: 0xf000-0xf03f (rw)
   Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
   IRQ: 39 (1207244 events)
   Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00000412sv00001028sd000005A4bc03sc00i00"
   Driver Info #0:
   Driver Status: i915 is active
   Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
   Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

   Primary display adapter: #20
3. Here's a screen capture before I changed the layout:

[image]

4. And here's what it looks like now (which is acceptable, just a bit odd that the top left (0,0) coordinate is not displayable...

[image]

Notice the change is that the portrait format display on the right is now higher than the landscape one on the left. The bottom however, is not cut off.

5. xrandr still hangs for ten or so seconds (which would be nice to fix)
6. The screenshot area still includes a gaping black waste of space on the right.

Comment: What kind of GPU are you running these off, and how are the displays arranged physically (and related) how are they arranged in the gnome settings display section. Perhaps a screenshot of that will be sufficient?

Comment: Just to clarify, the screens are configured by a script on login. That script is the four xrandr calls I listed.

Actually, that raises the other point that I'd actually prefer to to configure these at boot so they're already setup correctly for my login screen, rather than merely after login. I don't know how to do that, however.

Comment: Glad you got it acceptably working. My suspicion is that the Intel GPU chipset is limited in the number of pixels it can push. I have had similar issues where it went weird like this when the total horizontal or vertical pixel count went over some arbitrary limit set by the chipset. It was completely unfixable, as a limitation of the hardware. It feels much like that's what you're seeing.

Comment: I don't think it's a pixel limit, since it handles them well when I slide the rotated screen up a bit. Or rather slide the other two down a bit. But yeah, it's kinda working aside from the very long pauses when something interacts with the display system. Oh, and the mouse cursor flickers and hides at intervals, and the login screen mouse cursor remains in view on the logged in screen! It's kind of a mess to be honest, but this particular issue is worked round, yes, thanks.